# high loss rate when training my model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm working on image denoising using autoencoders (working with keras tensorflow backend).

when i train my model the loss rate is pretty high and stable(somewhere around 2.x).

i can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

here's my code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D,UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.

x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

# adding noise to images
noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_test.shape) 

x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)


input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (32, 7, 7)

x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')


autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train,
                nb_epoch=100,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test_noisy, x_test))
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you plot your training loss and validation loss curves? Seems that you are just following the example in the Keras tutorial.

Comment: It is difficult to find your issue with just the code you provided. Can you try to optimize `val_loss` with `AdamOptimizer`?